# React - Router add : but nothing to show on browser

Tags: reactjs, router

I added Router in index.js / App.js / Navbar.js as screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P01XS.png)
No errors in VSC, but errors in inspection[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkiQt.png)

I only edit the three pages.. please help..

npm install react-hook-form

Comment: Maybe, it won't solve your problem but you have misspelled at line 17 in index.js file.
path (not *prth)

Comment: Oh! THanks, well not working but never caught that typo lol

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.